# How to add more than one lines of the same CSS argument?

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is to add multiple lines of the same CSS argument three times, so the result would be equal to:

```
top: calc(....);
top: -moz-calc(....);
top: -webkit-calc(....);
```

I think it's obvious why would I like to do so.

The code so far is:

```
$('.nw_help_content').css('top', 'calc(-' + $(".nw_help_content").outerHeight() + 'px - 15px)');
```

...but from what I understood, adding similar line with another value of the same CSS argument would just override the old value.

Does any of you have any ideas how should I deal with this? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: When writing CSS that uses prefixes, always put the unprefixed version at the end, after the prefixed versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add vendor-specific prefixes to your CSS attributes. The point of jQuery is that it normalizes the browser and applies whichever vendor-specific prefix is required for you.

Comment: Is jQuery really that smart? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: @Mifeet - yes it is (at least, recent versions are... I can't remember when this came in... about 1.7, I think)

Comment: Whoa, jQuery surprises me every day.